# Error with Tutorial in Google Colab and GPU: "Failed to get convolution algorithm"

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, google-colaboratory, object-detection

when I run this tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_object_detection
on a GPU I get the following error: "Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above."

1. I do not have any warning log messages printed above the error message.
2. No issues if I run on a CPU.
3. I do not make any changes to the tutorial before execution.
4. Searching online I found that the problem may disappear if I reset the runtime. It does not work for me.
5. Searching online I found that the problem may be with the version of cuDNN. Before spending time to change the cuDNN version, I would like to know your opinions.

Please let me know if you need further information.

Thanks,
Federico

Comment: I got the same error. Resetting timeline won't help.

Comment: I tried to run on a TPU after reporting here my problem. As with a CPU, I have no issues with a TPU.

Comment: This tutorial is intended to produce a model that will be used either on CPU or on EdgeTPU mobile devices (whence the Edge TPU compilation section), not on GPU with CUDA/cuDNN. It would require NVIDIA to update cuDNN (upon which TensorFlow GPU relies) in order to work with TensorFlow Lite.  
A possible solution might be to train the model in the usual way: with TensorFlow GPU on a cuda enabled GPU and then convert the obtained model with TensorFlow Lite Converter to a TensorFlow Lite model (I haven't tested it.) But this is not done in this example.

Comment: Can you check the python logs, does all the packages load successfully, here an example :
Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11

Comment: `Failed to get convolution algorithm` is probably because of cuDNN. make sure you installed right version of cuDNN. Take a look at Tensorflow-gpu [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu).